# Create menu from all users with /home/ directory in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to write a bash script to remove cookies and cache from installed browsers on shared Ubuntu machines. The problem I am facing is in creating a menu where you can select either ALL users or individual users.

I am trying to create a main menu that calls either of the 2 functions (a work in progress) to perform the tasks (I have commented out the commands to run for the meantime).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove Browser cache from Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 18.04

# Check running as root/sudo
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ] ;then
echo -e "Please run with;\nsudo $0"
  exit
fi

# Enable extended globbing for the +(...) pattern
shopt -s extglob

## Check Ubuntu version
VERSION=$(lsb_release -d | awk -F":" '/Description/ {print $2}')
if [[ "$VERSION" = *"Ubuntu 18.04"* ]]; then
HOME_DIR="/home/ANT.DOMAIN.COM"
else
[[ "$VERSION" = *"Ubuntu 16.04"* ]]
HOME_DIR="/home/local/ANT"
fi

# Set Colours
RED='\033[1;31m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

## Clear Browser Cache for ALL Users
clear_cache_all () {
  mapfile -t PROFILES < <(find "$HOME_DIR" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
    for PRO in "${PROFILES[@]}"
    do
    # Check FireFox installed
    dpkg -s firefox &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      #rm -rf "$PRO"/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.sqlite "$PRO"/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js
      #rm -rf "$PRO"/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/*
      echo -e "FireFox Cookies & Cache Cleared for user ${GREEN}$USERNAME${NC}"
      else
      echo -e "${YELLOW}FireFox Not Installed...moving on${NC}"
    fi
    # Check Chromium installed
    dpkg -s chromium-browser &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      #rm -rf "$PRO"/.config/chromium/Default/
      #rm -rf "$PRO"/.cache/chromium
      echo -e "Chromium Cookies & Cache Cleared for user ${GREEN}$USERNAME${NC}"
      else
      echo -e "${YELLOW}Chromium Not Installed...moving on${NC}"
    fi
    # Check Chrome installed
    dpkg -s google-chrome-stable &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      #rm -rf "$PRO"/.config/google-chrome/Default/
      #rm -rf "$PRO"/.cache/google-chrome
      echo -e "Google Chrome Cookies & Cache Cleared for user ${GREEN}$USERNAME${NC}"
      else
      echo -e "${YELLOW}Google Chrome Not Installed...moving on${NC}"
    fi
    done
}

## Clear Cache for Individual Users
clear_cache_user () {
echo "stuff!"
}

# main menu function
main_menu () {
  clear
    if [ -d "$HOME_DIR" ]
    then
    mapfile -t USERS < <(find "$HOME_DIR" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
    # Get basename for users
    USERNAME="${USERS[@]##*/}"
    string="@(${USERNAME[0]}"
    for((i=1;i<${#USERNAME[@]};i++))
    do
      string+="|${USERNAME[$i]}"
    done
    string+=")"
    select NAME in "Clear ALL" "${USERNAME[@]}" "Quit"
    do
        case $NAME in
        "Clear ALL")
            # Call clear_cache_all Function
            clear_cache_all
            exit
            ;;
        $string)
            # Call clear_cache_user Function
            clear_cache_user
            ;;
        "Quit")
            exit
            ;;
            *)
            echo "Invalid option, please try again";;
        esac
    done
    else
      echo -e "${RED}Error: Cannot find home directories...exiting${NC}"
    fi
}

### SCRIPT COMMANDS ###
main_menu
```

Comment: So... What is the question?

Comment: The problem I am facing is in creating a menu where you can select either ALL users or individual users.... How do you do that?

Comment: Well that'd have to be a dynamically generated menu using something like /etc/passwd and their home directories (There is probably a better option). Are you struggling to find a list of the users or creating a menu? It's 2 completely different things are you struggling doing anything specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I can think of two options for your problem. I'll try to follow the names of your variables.

As I can see in your code, you have already put in the variable "string" all the usernames, so my first idea is to use a read and a simple if:

```
read -P "Insert ALL for all users, the Username for a single user, or Quit to exit: " NAME

if [ $NAME = "ALL" ]
then
    clear_cache_all
    exit
elif [ $NAME = "Quit" ]
then
    echo "Bye!"
    exit
else
    for i in "${string[@]}"
    do
        if [ "$i" == "$NAME" ] ; then
            clear_cache_user($NAME) #Guessing you'll pass the username as a variable to the function
            exit
        fi
    done
    echo "Invalid option, please try again"
fi
```

The other option is to use the case statement, as you were using. The problem is that case doesn't work easy with arrays, so while it's "case / in", it doesn't mean it's checking if the variable is an element of the array. In case you are forced to use case (or are in love with it), check this two links for some solutions: [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411001/using-case-and-arrays-together-in-bash) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177138/how-do-i-test-if-an-item-is-in-a-bash-array).

Hope this helps! Good luck!